# Get column sum and use to calculate percent of total, why doesn't work with CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculation

I did this following query, however it gave the the result of 0 for each orderStatusName, does anyone know where is the problem?

```
with tbl as (
      select s.orderstatusName, c.orderStatusId,count(c.orderId) counts 
      from [dbo].[ci_orders] c left join
           [dbo].[ci_orderStatus] s 
           on s.orderStatusId = c.orderStatusId
      where orderedDate between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-29'
      group by orderStatusName, c.orderStatusId
    )
select orderstatusName, counts/(select sum(counts) from tbl as PofTotal) from tbl
```

the result is :0

Comment: Integer division

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using what is known as integer math. When using 2 integers in SQL (Server) the return value is an integer as well. For example, `2 + 2 = 4`, `5 * 5 = 25`. The same applies to division `8 / 10 = 0`. That's because `0.8` isn't an integer, but the return value will be one (so the decimal points are lost).

The common way to change this behaviour is to multiply one of the expressions by `1.0`. For example:

```
counts/(select sum(counts) * 1.0 from tbl) as PofTotal
```

If you need more precision, you can increase the precision of the decimal value of `1.0` (i.e. to `1.000`, `1.0000000`, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Have a beautiful day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions and proper division:

```
select orderstatusName, counts * 1.0 / total_counts
from (select t.*, sum(counts) over () as total_counts
      from tbl
     ) t;
```

The reason you are getting `0` is because SQL Server does integer division when the operands are integers.  So, 1/2 = 0, not 0.5.